# How to print a list of strings using yields

Tags: python, python-3.x

could you please tell me how to have the following output using the code below?

Input list:

```
list_1 = ["A","house","49","apartment","AD","Luke","17","17","Mike","8","B","Eliz","22","www.odeon.com","64", "holidays"]
```

Code:

```
def splitting(N):
    for i in len(list_name):
        yield list_name[i:i + N]
```

Expected output:

```
1st group: ["A","house","49","apartment","AD"]
2nd group: ["Luke","17","17","Mike","8"]
3rd group: ["B","Eliz","22","www.odeon.com","64"]
4th group: ["holidays]
```

I have followed most of the previous questions that have been already published in stackoverflow, but I am still having difficulties. Since it might be a duplicated question, I would like to ask if it would be possible to help me to figure out with this function and the expected output before closing. Most of you have experience with Python: I am a beginner with lots of questions and with the necessity of asking a couple of them to learn more, even by my own mistakes.

Thank you

Comment: I would like to thank you both for helping me. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for loop with a skip and then yield slices:

```
list_1 = ["A","house","49","apartment","AD","Luke","17","17","Mike","8","B","Eliz","22","www.odeon.com","64", "holidays"]

def splitting(a_list, N):
    for i in range(0, len(a_list), N):
        yield a_list[i:i + N]

for item in splitting(list_1, 5):
    print(item)
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'house', '49', 'apartment', 'AD']
['Luke', '17', '17', 'Mike', '8']
['B', 'Eliz', '22', 'www.odeon.com', '64']
['holidays']
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, `i` is being incremented by one each time. So the second `yield` will return with `['house', '49', ...]` (a total of `N` items). Instead, you want `i` to be incremented by `N` each time. You can accomplish that like this:

```
def splitting(N):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_name) - N:
        yield list_name[i:i + N]  # while condition prevents IndexError
        i = i + N
    if i < len(list_name):
        yield list_name[i:]  # Yield what remains of the list
```